# Why must a substype assign a parent to to it's prototype outside the subtype's function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

If I assign a parent to my subtype's prototype inside my function, my subtype's prototype ends up pointing to Subtype instead of SuperType. Why is this?

```
function SubType( name ){
}               
SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); 

 // THE ABOVE WORKS :)

 function SubType(){
        SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); 
 }   

// THE ABOVE DOESN'T WORK :(
```

Comment: A bit off topic but if you want to inherit without calling the super constructor you can use `SubType.prototype=Object.create(SuperType)` this will set the SubType.prototype.constructor wrongly so you have to repair that if you use it or use a helper function to inherit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the way the `new` operator works in JavaScript. When you use `new` before a function call this is what happens:

1. We create a new object from the `prototype` of the function (e.g. `var instance = Object.create(func.prototype)`).
2. We set the `this` pointer of the function to the newly created object (e.g. `var result = func.apply(instance, arguments)`).
3. If the result is not an object or a function we return the instance (e.g. `if (typeof result === "object" || typeof result === "function") return result; else return instance;`).

Now forget everything else and only concentrate on the first point - the instance object creation phase.

**Example 1:**

```
function SubType(name) {
}

SubType.prototype = new SuperType;

// THE ABOVE WORKS :)
```

Here we're setting the `prototype` of `SubType` to `new SuperType` outside the constructor. Hence when you call `new SubType` JavaScript creates a new object which inherits from `SubType.prototype` which is `new SuperType` at that time. Hence the instance inherits from `SuperType` as well.

**Example 2:**

```
function SubType() {
    SubType.prototype = new SuperType;
}

// THE ABOVE DOESN'T WORK :(
```

Here we're calling `new SubType` before we set `SubType.prototype` to `new SuperType`. Hence the instance object inherits from `SubType.prototype` **before** it was set to `new SuperType`. Hence the instance doesn't inherit from `SuperType`.

**Conclusion:**

To understand how inheritance works in JavaScript I recommend you read the following articles:

1. [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743)
2. [No ways to have class-based objects in javascript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17008403/783743)
3. [javascript - Benefits of prototypal inheritance over classical? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16872315/783743)
4. [Aadit M Shah | Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/)

Answer (score 1):

Having it *inside* the constructor resets the `prototype` with each `new` instance created, but also requires that you create at least 1 instance for it to inherit.

```
function SubType(){
    SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); 
}

var before = SubType.prototype;
new SubType();

console.log(before === SubType.prototype);  // false

var current = SubType.prototype;
new SubType();

console.log(before === SubType.prototype);  // false
console.log(current === SubType.prototype); // false
console.log(before === current);            // false
```

Inheritance should typically be established before any instances are created, which requires the `prototype` chain be set *outside* the constructor:

```
function SubType() {}
SubType.prototype = new SuperType();

var before = SubType.prototype;

new SubType();

console.log(before === SubType.prototype); // true
```

Comment: When I run your example I get all 'trues'.

Answer (score -1):

Because you only have defined SubType in the second case, you haven't executed the function SubType.

```
function SubType( name ){
}               
SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); 

 // THE ABOVE WORKS :)

 function SubType(){
        SubType.prototype = new SuperType(); 
 }   

 SubType();

// THE ABOVE WILL WORK NOW
```