# Javascript Combination Inheritance - Unexpected Result

Tags: javascript

So I've read up and down on the topic of combination inheritance in JavaScript. I get that the intent is to use prototype chaining for to inherit properties and methods-- and use constructor stealing to inherit instance properties.

I've provided an example that is boggling me and preventing me from fully understanding this concept.

In a nutshell, I create a SuperColors parent function that passes along its properties to SubColors by a call() execution in the SubColors constructor method. As I understand it, this should allow the instance (instance1) to have its own color properties as I've demonstrated.

**Here's the quirky part.** I delete the instance1's property of colors. This should mean that when I push new colors they should manipulate SuperColors color property to the full rainbow. Then when I create a new instance (instance2) of SubColors they should inherit the rainbow.

They don't though. If we look at the instance2 in console.log() the colors were instantiated with "Red,Orange,Yellow", **even though** we can clearly see that SuperColor's color property has the entire rainbow.

This doesn't make sense to me-- am I understanding prototype inheritance incorrectly or is this a weird quirk of the language that is unexpected?

```
function SuperColors() {
    this.colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow"];
}

SuperColors.prototype.sayColors = function () {
    alert("SuperColors " + this.colors);
};

function SubColors() {
    //inherit properties
    SuperColors.call(this);
}

// inherit methods
SubColors.prototype = new SuperColors();

SubColors.prototype.sayRainbow = function () {
    alert(this.colors + "a whole rainbow!");
};

// create an instance of SubColors
var instance1 = new SubColors();

// push colors to colors property on instance
instance1.colors.push("green", "blue", "purple");
alert(instance1.colors); // "red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple"
instance1.sayColors(); // "SuperColors red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple";

// delete instance of colors
delete(instance1.colors);
console.log(instance1);

// this should manipulate SuperColor's constructor of colors
instance1.colors.push("green", "blue", "purple");

// instantiate a new SubColor object that should inherit SuperColor's entire rainbow
var instance2 = new SubColors();

alert(instance1.colors);
alert(instance2.colors); // WHY ISN'T THIS THE ENTIRE RAINBOW? It should have been instantiated with SuperColor's modified colors.

console.log(instance2); // Shows that SuperColors.colors has the rainbow, but the instance has only 3 colors?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKAZf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // this should manipulate SuperColor's constructor of colors
> delete instance1.colors;
> instance1.colors.push("green", "blue", "purple");
> ```

Not exactly. It doesn't manipulate the `SuperColor` constructor, but the `SubColor.prototype` (a `SuperColor` instance), from which the `instance1` inherits its `.colors` property (now that it has no own one any more).

> ```
> // instantiate a new SubColor object that should inherit SuperColor's entire rainbow
> var instance2 = new SubColors();
> ```

No, nothing changed in the inheritance process. `instance2` still inherits from `SubColor.prototype` just as `instance1` does. And the `SuperColor` constructor is still called on the new instance…

> ```
> alert(instance2.colors); // WHY ISN'T THIS THE ENTIRE RAINBOW?
> ```

…where it creates a brand new array which is assigned to a new, **own** `.colors` property of the new instance! That new array is the one you're accessing, and it was never modified by anything.

If you would

```
delete instance2.colors;
```

then you could see the `SubColor.prototype.colors` as well when doing

```
alert(instance2.colors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `instance2.colors`. Then you'll get the entire rainbow:

```
delete instance2.colors;
alert(instance2.colors);
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKAZf/1/

You should read the following posts on inheritance in JavaScript:

1. [Aadit M Shah | Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/)
2. [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property/8096017#8096017)
3. [Benefits of prototypal inheritance over classical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800964/benefits-of-prototypal-inheritance-over-classical/16872315#16872315)
4. [No ways to have class-based objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008086/no-ways-to-have-class-based-objects-in-javascript/17008403#17008403)

Comment: But I shouldn't have to do that for every instance when making a new instance. The question is more about why every new instance doesn't instantiate with the rainbow spectrum when clearly SuperColors color property is "red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's down to this:

```
function SubColors() {
    //inherit properties
    SuperColors.call(this);
}
```

What you are doing here is executing `SuperColors` but making `this` refer to the `SubColors` instance you're creating.  Inside `SuperColors` the `SubColors` instance then gets given its own `colors` property - *this hides the `colors` attribute on prototype*.

So, when something tries to look up `colors` on your `SubColours` instance it finds something *on that instance* and doesn't look up the prototype chain any further.  When you delete `colors` on `instance1` subsequent lookups of `instance1.colors` now have to look up the prototype chain to find the `SuperColors` version, but when you create `instance2`, you are again creating `colors` on the `SubColors` instance which hides the version on `SuperColors`.

If you `delete instance2.colors` you will see that `instance2.colors` now resolves to the version of `colors` with teh whole rainbow.